# How can I get phantom to "execute" my page?

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs

I have a script tag inside my page but it isn't being run. It is simply rendered.

I have the following code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph,error) {
  c = callback;
  ph.createPage(function( page,err ) {  
    page.setContent( output );
    callback = c;
    setTimeout(function() {
       page.evaluate(function() {
         return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
       }, function(html) {
         callback(html);
       });
    }, 5000);
  });
});
```

How do I tell phantom to "load"/"execute" the page so that the script on the page runs? (I don't want to use page.open)

Also, content is `"<p>Page <strong>1</strong> content.</p><button id=\"page1_button\">button</button><script>document.getElementsByTagName('p').innerHTML = 'test';</script>"`

Answer (score 0):

Call `page.open`, see http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage for arguments.

The first argument is a url, the second one is a callback.

In the callback to `page.open` you should then call `page.evaluate` as you previously tried.

```
page.open("http://httpbin.org/get", function(status) {
    if (status == "success") {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            // ...
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Right, the problem is I don't want to make a request when I have the document I want to render locally. Is there another way??

Comment: You can use the webserver module if you absolutely have to do whatever it is you're trying to do.